# Compiling and running infinite for loop with codeblocks

Tags: c++, c, windows, for-loop, codeblocks

```
int main()
{
for (;;)
    printf("This is a loop");
    //getch();
return 0;
}
```

Running the executable from inside Codeblocks, it returns nothing but make the program unusable one i.e. like hang the program. It is not expected to do that. But if the executable is started from outside (directly double clicking the .exe) it return the print() text. It means that either the System or Codeblocks cannot handle this loop or executable or that the executable may have some sort of error. But I don't understand why the the compilation is fine while executing from Codeblocks. The executable itself is 32bit (x86) and running it from a 32bit or 64bit cmd doesn't make a change.

I have also tried the same with eclipse and so on. But same outcome for both the IDE.

Comment: is this code meant to go forever? The way you have it written, it will.  There is nothing in there to stop the loop

Comment: Hi DJ Burb, Thanks for the comment. Its just a testing loop; that can run without any termination condition otherwise it require any manual intervention to exit the program or the loop. I know that. For you info : Please consider the below:


`#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char command[80], temp[80];
    int i, j;
    for ( ; ; ){
        printf("Which operation do you want to perform?\n");
        gets(command);
        /** check if the user want to terminate the program**/
        if(!strcmp(command, "quit")) break;
  }

    return 0;
}`

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. It is not formatted as source code and is hard to read. Also, I imagine that the infinite loop + constant I/O is what is causing your IDE(s) to hang when you run the executable.

Comment: In C++11, loops must terminate or your program exhibits undefined behavior (according to the language specification), and the compiler can assume that they do. Compilers (namely clang) will remove infinite loops altogether if it detects it, making it run the fastest infinite loop ever.

Comment: the difference in the two methods of running the program is one method uses buffered output while the other does not use buffering.  The simple fix is to (either) append a '\n' to the string or (preferred) add the line: fflush(stdout); after the printf() line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdout` is usually buffered until either you print a newline character `\n` or you call `fflush(stdout)`. Also, printing in an infinite loop can cause other problems depending on how `stdout` is being handled by the IDE.

I recommend that you change the loop to

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    printf( "This is a loop\n" );
```

Comment: @ user3386109 Thanks much for the answer. Though its correct but I was looking for solution with infinite loop.